# My Bitcoin Transfer is unconfirmed and its 2 days

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Can anyone help me please? I tried withdrawal money via yobit to another wallet but I see no issue on Yobit's side. Can anyone tell me how to get it done right away? My withdrawal BTC is really lesser like $200 so I can't pay $150 for the transaction to accelerate :/

This is not duplicate since I have paid much fee $0.0008 already for transaction.

Comment: It's a duplicate again. You could give us the transaction id so that we could tell you if the fee is ok or too low.

Comment: I don't think fee is the issue here please see the 2 transactions I did and it's stuck

827af3bb0c34637c7d0f689a82e6a47fab9af7daacc8632910af4a779e20b267

Comment: f21ccdfac78d9adc9686e8fb2ca54ac1a8504fa4a54a6c31a87f9125bd6eff46